# how do I make an empty block of code in Swift?

Tags: swift

One of my cases in a switch currently does nothing, but might in the future. I want to leave it in there and have a note to myself to that effect. But apparently you can't:

```
case CardTypes.None: // do nothing for now
```

causes an *error* that "'case' label in a 'switch' should have at least one executable statement". I have no idea why anyone would consider that to be an *error* and not a *warning* (if even that!). So then I tried

```
case CardTypes.None: { } // do nothing for now
```

Returns "Braced block of statements is an unused closure", another *error*.

Is there some magic invocation I'm missing here?

Comment: The Swift documentation explicitly notes: *"Although break is not required in Swift, you can still use a break statement to match and ignore a particular case, ..."*

Answer (score 2):

That's the only case where the `break` statement is used in a `switch` statement: it indicates that there's no code associated to a `case`. So in your code:

```
case CardTypes.None: break
```

means "do nothing in this case".

Documented in [No Implicit Fallthrough](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_200)

Comment: Gah! This is certainly the most idiosyncratic language I have ever used. break = empty statement, let = const, var = dim, colon = whatever... Thanks again Antonio, you've clearly gotten further into Swift than I.

Comment: IMO typical from Apple using different names to describe the same thing :) Note however that let != const: a const is a constant resolved at compilation, let instead is an immutable, which is determined at runtime, but once set it cannot be modified. More flexible than const in many cases.